How do I safely type a function that accepts a generic container class?
from __future__ import annotations

import logging
from datetime import datetime, UTC
from typing import Any, Generic, Self, Protocol, TypeVar

from pydantic import AwareDatetime, BaseModel

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
EventDataT_co = TypeVar('EventDataT_co')


class Event(BaseModel, Generic[EventDataT_co]):
    raised_at: AwareDatetime
    data: tuple[EventDataT_co, ...]

    @classmethod
    def from_data(cls, *data: EventDataT_co) -> Self:
        return cls(raised_at=datetime.now(UTC), data=data)


class EventRepository(Protocol):
    def save_events_unsafe(self, *events: Event[Any]) -> None:  # same as `*events: Event[Any]`
        """not type-safe (someone might make unsafe assumption on `.data`)"""

    def save_events_safe(self, *events: Event[object]) -> None:
        """Only allowed if Event is covariant, but then I can't have a custom constructor"""

    def save_events_gen(self, *events: Event[EventDataT_co]) -> None:
        """It implies this is a generic function, when it's more `.data`-agnostic"""


class InheritedEventRepository(EventRepository):
    def save_events_unsafe(self, *events: Event[Any]) -> None:
        logger.info(str([data.id for event in events for data in event.data]))  # Type-checker says ok, dev made an uncaught mistake

    def save_events_safe(self, *events: Event[object]) -> None:
        logger.info(str([data.id for event in events for data in event.data]))  # Type-checker says error: "object" has no attribute "id"  [attr-defined]

    def save_events_gen(self, *events: Event[EventDataT_co]) -> None:
        logger.info(str([data.id for event in events for data in event.data]))
        # Type-checker error: "EventDataT_co" has no attribute "id"  [attr-defined] if covariant
        # No error if invariant


event_1 = Event.from_data(1)
event_2 = Event.from_data('foo')
from typing import reveal_type
print(reveal_type(event_1))  # Event[builtins.int]
print(reveal_type(event_2))  # Event[builtins.str]
InheritedEventRepository().save_events_unsafe(event_1, event_2)
InheritedEventRepository().save_events_safe(event_1, event_2)
# error: Argument 1 to "save_events_safe" of "InheritedEventRepository" has incompatible type "Event[int]"; expected "Event[object]"  [arg-type] if invariant
# No error if covariant
InheritedEventRepository().save_events_gen(event_1, event_2)
# error: Cannot infer type argument 1 of "save_events_gen" of "InheritedEventRepository"  [misc] if invariant
# No error if covariant

Mypy throws:

error: Cannot use a covariant type variable as a parameter  [misc]

on the def from_data(...) constructor line. I don't want to make Event covariant but it seems the only way to allow save_events_safe to be accepted by mypy? I don't want to use Event[Any] in save_events because save_events will be subclassed (I wouldn't want the dev that inherits from it to have no type-checking safety). Finally, save_events_gen(self, *events: Event[EventDataT_co]) has the same problem as save_events_safe (covariant only)
That means I'm either stuck with a covariant version that doesn't allow a custom constructor (also, Event really shouldn't be used covariantly outside of this case), or an invariant one that forces me to use Any for agnostic functions. How do I solve this ?

If the class where save_events is defined is also generic (and it takes an Event[T]), does that solve the problem?

That would make that class Generic[Event[T]], meaning an instance of that class could only take one specific type of event (e.g.: Event[Foo]). That wouldn't work. The class is agnostic, not generic. In essence, I should use Event[Any], but that would disable type-checking and a subclass might accidentally make an illegal attribute access. Hence Event[object] :/

It might help to expand your example to demonstrate the problem that occurs if you use Any.  I'm unclear how/why this class is allowed to access data at all if it's meant to be entirely agnostic to its type.

It's not allowed to access attributes on data, but it might access data. That's the point, I can't control what another dev will do when inheriting that class if I use Any. object prevents this type of access. (If that helps to understand, I'm creating a library which will be used by other devs).

What does it mean to "access" data but not its attributes???  Again, a code sample would be really useful.

Accessing data : event.data -> legal  / Accessing an attribute of data : event.data.id -> illegal. I hope this clears things up for you.

Didn't have much time yesterday, sorry. I've updated the code. I hope this makes the problem clearer. As stated in my original question (it was edited out), I'm not well versed in generics variance. I've read the docs, I do understand, but I'm not juggling with the concept with ease. I've spent the last 4 days making a small-ish repo mypy-compliant and it's been hell (specifically because it's a dev-oriented library). Trying to explain the problem in a succinct form was a challenge in itself. I'm also not sure I understand what was missing initially, but I hope the revised version helps.

This is something I myself have faced before, let's state the facts:

Event is Generic - makes sense, it's some class that has generic properties to be overwritten by library users
We want a function that uses Event, but that doesn't care about what it's properties are outside of those that are generic.

This representation:
def save_events(*events: Event[T]): ...

Satisfies all of these conditions - being "data-agnostic" and being "generic" are effectively the same thing, if you think of generic as "independent of the properties of some internal section".
But what about the covariance issue?
The below code segment:
from __future__ import annotations
from datetime import datetime, UTC
from typing import  Generic, Self, TypeVar
from pydantic import AwareDatetime, BaseModel


EventDataT = TypeVar('EventDataT')

class Event(BaseModel, Generic[EventDataT]):
    raised_at: AwareDatetime
    data: tuple[EventDataT, ...]

    @classmethod
    def from_data(cls, *data: EventDataT) -> Self:  
        return cls(raised_at=datetime.now(UTC), data=data)


EventDataT_co = TypeVar('EventDataT_co', covariant=True)


def save_events(*events: Event[EventDataT_co]): ...

class Test:
    pass

save_events(Event[Test].from_data(Test()))

...type checks just fine for me in both pyright and mypy strict mode. By introducing a new type var we can make one co-variant and the other not co-variant. Hope this helps!

Apologies, I've just noticed the question updated while I was writing that, but I think it all still applies.

Thank you !!!! I didn't even know I could do that (redefine a new TypeVar for a different usage).
